# Update Quantity inside of DataGridView not change the Total

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access, datagridview

i have a problem. Here is my problem:

I got something like this in my DataGridView:

`Product Code || Quantity || Description || SubTotal || Total || ....... (and so on)`

`SM0001 for the Product Code,
100 for the Quantity,
AS 5 for the Description,
10,000 for the Sub Total, and 1,000,000 for the Total`

The above it's correct because `10,000` times `100` we get `1,000,000`

I add data to the DataGridView and when the data has been added to the DataGridView, i click edit in that DataGridView, when i change some value on it, it will be changed and updated. But, the problem is when i tried to change the "Quantity" from `100` to `500`, it didn't change the `Total`, the `Total` suppose to update and change too based on `Quantity * Sub Total` (because i change the `Quantity`)

How is it like that?

Here is the code for my problem above when i tried to update it from DataGridView:

```
private void DataGridViewCalculation(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int _quantity = Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value);
                int _subTotal = Convert.ToInt32(this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].Value);
                int _total = Convert.ToInt32(_quantity * _subTotal);

                this.dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[4].Value = _total;
            }

            dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = _ds.Tables[0];
        }
```

Here is the screenshot of my problem above after and before i change the quantity to 500 from 100:

[image]

**Screenshot above display when i haven't change the `Quantity` to `500` (still at 100)**

[image]

**Screenshot above display when i already changed the `Quantity` to `500`, but the `Total` still the same as `Quantity 100`**

Basically, i want when user click EDIT in DataGridView and made changes in it (let's say user make changes on `Quantity` in DataGridView, the `Total` in DataGridView should change too)

**EDITED**:

```
dataGridView1.CellValueChanged += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(this.DataGridViewCalculation);

private void DataGridViewCalculation(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals(1))
            {
                int _total = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1["Quantity", e.RowIndex].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1["SubTotal", e.RowIndex].Value);
                dataGridView1["Total", e.RowIndex].Value = _total.ToString();
            }
        }
```

**NOTE**:

The edited code still not working when i tried to change the `Quantity` value, the `Total` still remains same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `CellValueChanged` event. This event will be raised when cell value is changed.
Basically what you have to do is,

- Check if the Quantity cell is edited by checking column index
- Get the value of `Sub Total` column and `Quantity` in the same row using `RowIndex` of the edited cell.
- Multiply both and set it to the `Total` cell.

`Sample Code`

*Please note that this is a sample code, You may have to consider converting values to the required numeric format before performing any operation.*

```
    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals("column Index of Quantity"))
        {
            double total = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1["Subtotal column name", e.RowIndex].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1["Quantity column name", e.RowIndex].Value);
            dataGridView1["Total Column name", e.RowIndex].Value = total.ToString();
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Sir, how do i change the `if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals("Column Index of Quantity"))?` i should change the `""` with what? the program said it is `object`

Comment: @Kaoru column index of your Quantity column, if its 3rd column in the grid then index should be 2. Just give the number without doube qoutes.

Comment: i already did that sir, but when i run the program and change the `Quantity` value after it has been added to the DataGridView, the `Total` still remains same. Not changing based on current `Quantity` (Still at previous `Quantity`, which is after i added to the DataGridView and not yet edit the DataGridView), i will edit the code in the question above.

Comment: @Kaoru this event will fire only when the edited cell lose focus. after editing the cell just click Tab on keyboard.

Comment: yeah, i already did that sir, but the `Total` didn't change. Before i end the editing mode in DataGridView, i pressed the TAB on the keyboard first, and when the editing mode is end, then i just click `OK` button, this `OK` button is to save all the changes in DataGridView and update it to the database and in DataGridView.

Comment: This should work perfectly. Can you put a debug point and see what happens when you edit the cell. then you can easily figure out what happens.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/38183/discussion-between-accessdenied-and-kaoru)

Comment: i already put the breakpoint in the `if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals(1))`, and when i change the `Quantity` value and press TAB, the program stop at the breakpoint (so it is true), but when i place breakpoint in the below `if(e.Columnindex.Equals(1))`, the program didn't stop at all, although i already placed the breakpoint in here : `int _total = Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1["Quantity", e.RowIndex].Value) * Convert.ToInt32(dataGridView1["SubTotal", e.RowIndex].Value);`

Comment: @Kaoru that means column index of your Quantity cell is wrong.