# DataGridView update Cell Value while typing

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a data grid view with QUANTITY, UNIT PRICE and VALUE columns. What I want to do is when changing the QUANTITY I need to change the VALUE .
VALUE = QUANTITY * UNIT PRICE

I wrote code for gridview 'CellValueChanged' event. But then VALUE will change when leaving the cell only. I need to change VALUE when typing the QUANTITY.

My code like this.Any idea please.

```
private void dgvSale_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvSale.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Qty")
    {
       double qty = Convert.ToDouble(dgvSale["Qty", dgvSale.CurrentRow.Index].Value);
       double rate = Convert.ToDouble(dgvSale["Rate", dgvSale.CurrentRow.Index].Value);
       double totVal = qty * rate;
       dgvSale["Value", dgvSale.CurrentRow.Index].Value = totVal.ToString("#,###.00");
    }
 }
```

Comment: maybe you should try to rebind the datasource of the grid

Comment: The keydown event happens while typing, but what will you do when the input is not yet valid?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if I understood you right. You're trying to update the value on the fly, while typing? If so then you probably should use also **DataGridView.CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged** event to commit cell value changes. Below is the example based on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcelldirtystatechanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private void dgvSale_CurrentCellDirtyStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (dgvSale.IsCurrentCellDirty)
    {
        dgvSale.CommitEdit(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts.Commit);
    }
}
```

Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes. That's wht I needed. Now VALUE is updating while typing the Quantity.

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex.Equals("column Index of Quantity"))
    {
        double total = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1["Subtotal column name", e.RowIndex].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView1["Quantity column name", e.RowIndex].Value);
        dataGridView1["Total Column name", e.RowIndex].Value = total.ToString();
    }            
}
```

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19050639/update-quantity-inside-of-datagridview-not-change-the-total)